# CSS leaked in angular project - mat-paginator drop-down is overflowing bellow page

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, mat-pagination

I am using Angular-13 application with material UI components.
We have recently migrated from angular-8 application to Angular-13, while doing so & with recent changes, my  mat paginator is not working as expected. Now the drop-down is overflowing and getting outside the page.
Similarly matToolTip position also changed(going way above)
Check bellow screenshot
[image: Drop-down overflowing bellow page]

I tried following things,

1. Removed all the !important statement from the project
2. Removed whole CSS from styles.scss file & checked
3. One by one removed css from all component files & checked
4. Tried adding different different CSS to paginator component.

Is there any way to identify which CSS is doing this, or how can I fix it.